# How do I use mvn test with multiple modules?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, maven

I have two maven modules, A and AB, with AB depending on test files in A. Both reference a parent pom.

I discovered the magic of [test-jar](http://beust.com/weblog/2010/08/15/yaml-the-forgotten-victim-of-the-format-wars/) which allowed me to compile my program, but I still cannot run tests with mvn test.

Strangely enough, mvn package tests seems to work.

Here's my basic configuration:

```
 ...
 <parent>
   <groupId>com.acme.parent</groupId>
   <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
   <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
   <version>1.0</version>
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
 <artifactId>A</artifactId>     
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <version>1.0</version>
 ...

 <build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>test-jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Project AB (depends on A)

```
...
<parent>
  <groupId>com.acme.parent</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>AB</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>A</artifact>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>A</artifact>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
...
```

And finally, the relevant bits from the parent pom:

```
...
<groupId>com.acme.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
  <module>A</module>
  <module>AB</module>
</module>
...
```

So, with all that said, how do I make mvn tests run as expected?

I'm using maven 2.2.1 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to one of the unresolved bugs like [MNG-3559](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3559).

Essentially, the test classes of Project A are not visible to Project AB if only `mvn test` is run from parent pom.  They are visible once the jar for package A is created (during the `package` phase).